# Error with self invoking anonymous functions in Lua

Tags: function, lambda, lua, interpreter

I'm trying to use self invoking anonymous functions in Lua, and am seeing some strange behavior.

This:

```
(function ()
  print("self-invoking approach")
end)()

print("standard approach")
```

works ok and prints the following output:

```
self-invoking approach
standard approach
```

but reversing the two:

```
print("standard approach")

(function ()
  print("self-invoking approach")
end)()
```

results in this error:

```
➜  hammerspoon   lua temp.lua
standard approach
lua: temp.lua:1: attempt to call a nil value
stack traceback:
    temp.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Strangely, when code is run in the Lua REPL, the failure only occurs when the function form is second, and both calls are wrapped in an outer function that is called:

```
function foo()
    print("standard approach")

    (function ()
      print("self-invoking approach")
    end)()
end

foo()
```

What's happening here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a parsing ambiguity. The non-working case is being parsed as:

```
print("standard approach")(function ()
  print("self-invoking approach")
end)()
```

In other words, it's printing `standard approach`, then taking the return value of that `print` (which is `nil`), and trying to call that with your self-invoking function as the argument (after which it would have tried to call the result of that too, had it not already crashed). To fix it, add a semicolon at the end of the first `print` function call.

Comment: It's not an ambiguity. The parser takes the longest valid expression.

Comment: @lhf Isn't it though? I'd argue that it is an ambiguity, and taking the longest valid expression is how it chooses to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: Also, in Lua 5.1, it really did fail to parse with the error `ambiguous syntax (function call x new statement)`.

Comment: Wow! I'm astonished. Do other languages share this behavior? I don't think I've ever seen it before. I decided to place the ";" directly before the function definition (`;(function...`) to be certain that it would never be considered part of a prior statement.

Comment: Try this in javascript: `console.log("test") ( () => console.log("foo"))()` same problem, same solution (adding a `;`). This happens because parentheses are used for more than one thing in many programming languages, which can lead to these ambiguities.